# Solr Indexing & Searching

Tags: solr

Could anyone suggest me the best way of using solr for my regular search for my products and also it should support synonyms & fuzzy search also ?

suppose if I search with word cro, I need products starting with cro, then cro occurrences anywhere in the field, then synonyms & then fuzzy on it in the respective boosting

Answer (score 0):

i have a scenario for my project.

i am using together **FuzzyLookupFactory**(with multiple suggester) and **AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory**. i am using solrj (java api) for request query.

first i search word with analyzinginfixlookupfactory this could find word anywhere in the field but you have to input correctly. for example product name "**toshiba**" if you search "**tosh**" it could find "**toshiba**" correctly but if you search "**toshba**" it will not find any product.

this time i am using fuzzylookupfactory suggester i split all words(for example you have "toshiba laptop"  word1=toshiba word2 = laptop etc.) and search one to one and fuzzy will find toshba -> toshiba and after find toshiba again use analyzinginfixlookupfactory  for find complete product field.

for example you want to find "**toshiba laptop**" and you searched "**toshba laptp**". first try "analyzinginfixlookupfactory" and response will be null.After response null search fuzzy for each word and add what you find like toshba -> toshiba  + laptp-> laptop it will toshiba laptop and now you can search again analyzinginfixlookupfactory for complete field.

my analyzing suggester in (solrconfig.xml)

```
<searchComponent name="suggestAnalyzing" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">suggestAnalyzing</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
<str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggester_fuzzy_dir</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggester_infix_dir</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>  
<str name="field">COMPLETE_FIELD</str>
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>

 <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
 <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
 <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
 </lst>


 </searchComponent>

 <requestHandler name="/suggestAnalyzing" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
 <str name="suggest.dictionary">suggestAnalyzing</str>
 <str name="suggest">true</str>
 <str name="suggest.count">10</str>

 </lst>
 <arr name="components">
 <str>suggestAnalyzing</str>
 </arr>
 </requestHandler>
```

my fuzzy suggester in (solrconfig.xml)

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SuggestComponent" name="suggest">

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">word1suggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">word1</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->   
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">word2suggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">word2</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/word2suggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">word3suggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">word3</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/word3suggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="preserveSep">true</str>
<str name="preservePositionIncrements">true</str>
<str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str> 
<float name="threshold">0.005</float> 
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>

</lst>

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">word4suggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">word4</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/word4suggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="preserveSep">true</str>
<str name="preservePositionIncrements">true</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">word5suggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">word5</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/word5suggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="preserveSep">true</str>
<str name="preservePositionIncrements">true</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">word6suggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">word6</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/word6suggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="preserveSep">true</str>
<str name="preservePositionIncrements">true</str>
<str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str> 
<float name="threshold">0.005</float> 
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>


<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">word7suggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">word7</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/word7suggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="preserveSep">true</str>
<str name="preservePositionIncrements">true</str>
<str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str> 
<float name="threshold">0.005</float> 
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">word8suggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">word8</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive  suggestions from -->
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/word8suggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="preserveSep">true</str>
<str name="preservePositionIncrements">true</str>
<str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str> 
<float name="threshold">0.005</float> 
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>


</searchComponent>

<requestHandler class="solr.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="spellcheck">true</str>
<str name="suggest">true</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">word1suggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">word2suggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">word3suggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">word4suggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">word5suggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">word6suggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">word7suggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">word8suggester</str>

<str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>

</lst>
<arr name="components">
<str>suggest</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

my managed-schema fields

```
<fieldType name="textgen" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
        ignoreCase="true"
        words="stopwords.txt"

        />
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="word1" type="textgen" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="COMPLETE_FIELD" type="textgen" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="word2" type="text_general" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="word3" type="text_general" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="word4" type="textgen" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="word5" type="textgen" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="word6" type="textgen" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="word7" type="textgen" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="word8" type="textgen" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```